# vertical pod autoscaler not working when receiving load from a benchmark tool

Tags: kubernetes, devops, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, infrastructure

I have a container based application that is used to receive load from a benchmark tool and generate memory and cpu utilization. So I created this deployment file to the app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: slave-leech-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: slave-leech-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: slave-leech-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: slave-leech
        image: kewynakshlley/slave-leech
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
```

Also I have the service  and the vertical pod autoscaler manifest:

Service:

````
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: slave-leech-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    app: slave-leech-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer```


vertical pod auto scaler manifest:

``` apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       slave-leech-deployment
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Auto"
````

When I run the benchmark tool I can see the cpu utilization reaching the limit but the VPA isn't triggered and the container is not recreated with more resources.

[cpu utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDsVc.png)

output of kubectl describe vpa my-vpa

```
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2","kind":"VerticalPodAutoscaler","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-vpa","namespace":"defaul...
API Version:  autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2
Kind:         VerticalPodAutoscaler
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-01-21T22:59:28Z
  Generation:          19
  Resource Version:    20357
  Self Link:           /apis/autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2/namespaces/default/verticalpodautoscalers/my-vpa
  UID:                 a5958daa-9274-4904-b706-bb81e4948599
Spec:
  Target Ref:
    API Version:  apps/v1
    Kind:         Deployment
    Name:         slave-leech-deployment
  Update Policy:
    Update Mode:  Recreate
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-01-21T23:00:07Z
    Message:               No pods match this VPA object
    Reason:                NoPodsMatched
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NoPodsMatched
    Last Transition Time:  2020-01-21T23:00:07Z
    Status:                True
    Type:                  RecommendationProvided
  Recommendation:
    Container Recommendations:
      Container Name:  slave-leech
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:     25m
        Memory:  262144k
      Target:
        Cpu:     126m
        Memory:  262144k
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:     126m
        Memory:  262144k
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:     1490m
        Memory:  428775530
Events: 
         <none>
```

Comment: Images are hard for us, copy & paste the codes directly here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please use the code syntax highlight option in the editor to include the required code in the question itself, rather than a picture. If you need to add a picture, add the picture itself and not a link to the picture. Links go broken soon enough.

Comment: @BMW I alreaady did that, so can U help now?

Comment: Could you please tell us where is your cluster located?

Comment: @OhHiMark I am using minikube for testing purposes.

Comment: Try running this command to see the exact CPU requests on the pods: `kubectl get pod -n dev -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,PHASE:.status.phase,CPU-REQUEST:.spec.containers\[0\].resources.requests.cpu` Than compare it with your configured recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pod's max CPU utilization is .097 which is less than 1 core, upperbound for your recommendation is 1490m (1.4 core), so VPA will not reschedule.  `The VerticalPodAutoscaler uses the lowerBound and upperBound recommendations to decide whether to delete a Pod and replace it with a new Pod. If a Pod has requests less than the lower bound or greater than the upper bound, the VerticalPodAutoscaler deletes the Pod and replaces it with a Pod that has the target recommendation`

[Vertical Pod Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/vertical-pod-autoscaling)

[Understanding Resource Limits in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-cpu-time-9eff74d3161b)

Comment: I just tried to increase the CPU limit and still not working. Maybe it is something related to the service manifest?

Comment: Thanks @ffran09, your answer was quite helpful. But right now I am running my benchmark and my lower bound is 122m and my request is 50m and the container is not being recreated.

Comment: `Recommendation:
    Container Recommendations:
      Container Name:  slave-leech
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:     122m
        Memory:  262144k
      Target:
        Cpu:     1168m
        Memory:  262144k
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:     1168m
        Memory:  262144k
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:     16458m
        Memory:  1102219048
Events:          <none>`

Comment: kubectl top pods says that cpu usage is 998m and memory is 58Mi.

Answer (score 0):

ffran09 is right with his/her answer but I would like to add some more info.

As already stated in my comment:

Try running this command to see the exact CPU requests on the pods:

```
kubectl get pod -n dev -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,PHASE:.status.phase,CPU-REQUEST:.spec.containers\[0\].resources.requests.cpu
```

Than compare it with your configured recommendations.

This will help you to observe the actual resource utilization and therefore setup the proper limits for your VPA.

I also recommend you to use a `metrics-server` for ingesting a pod metrics. Minikube includes it as a bundled add-on:

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

For more details regarding that part and other vital elements of VPA I highly recommend you to go through these resources:

- [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#vertical-pod-autoscaler)
- [Vertical Pod Autoscaling in Kubernetes](https://livewyer.io/blog/2019/06/24/vertical-pod-autoscaling/)

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: The command returns empty fields: NAME PHASE CPU-REQUEST. Also I am using metrics-server.

Comment: kubectl top pods returns: ```kubectl top pods
NAME                                      CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
slave-leech-deployment-7f48f75997-ccj4f   975m         37Mi ```